# URL CODIFICAR Y DECODIFICAR POR PHP

Tags: php, html

> Saludos-. estoy tratando de codificar y decoficar una url pero solo me
> codifica, este es elcodigo que estoy probando

```
<?php
// Codificamos o encriptamos el link 
$cadena = "ver-album.php";
$url = urlencode(base64_encode($cadena));

//Resultado codificado //
echo ".$url.";

//Decodificamos o descriptamos el link 
$url = urlencode(base64_decode($cadena));


// Aqui deberia ser la url decodificada 
echo "<a href='".$url."'> ir </a>"

?>
```

Comment: Al decodificar, solo coloca `base64_decode(urldecode($url));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas decodificando una variable que no es. Además tienes errores de escritura. Usas **urlencode** dos veces.

```
<?php
    $cadena = "ver-album.php";
    $url = base64_encode(urlencode($cadena));

    //Resultado codificado
    echo $url;

    //Decodificamos o descriptamos el link
    echo "<br><br>".$url = base64_decode(urldecode($url));


    // Aqui deberia ser la url decodificada
    echo "<br><br><a href='".$url."'> ir </a>"

    /*
    Resultado:
    dmVyLWFsYnVtLnBocA==

    ver-album.php

    ir // este es el link

    */
```

Al final, el link se muestra correctamente.

Comment: Hola Ochoa, el primer paso es al revez. Primero tenes que usar `base64_encode` y al resultado aplicarle `urlencode`.

Comment: Hola marcos, el codigo de ochoa me ha funcionado, pero por intriga por lo que dices como quedaria?

Comment: @Marcos, si lo hago al revés no me ha funcionado. Me genera un error de símbolos, justo por eso invertí los métodos. Al hacerlo como lo puse, el resultado es el esperado

Comment: @OCHOA, no se bien que error te dio, pero sería lo correcto. [Aca una demo](https://onlinephp.io/c/822df7). Pensa en el orden que estas aplicando los métodos, lo lógico sería que vuelvas sobre tus pasos.

Comment: Hola @Noveember, por lo que menciono en el comentario anterior a éste. Saludos!

Comment: @OCHOA,@Marcos, gracias por su colaboracion de antemano (Y)

Comment: me sale este error Invalid utf8 character string: 'n\xBF'

Comment: @Marcos, si gusta lo seguimos en un chat y le explico mejor, o me explica mejor :-p

Comment: @OCHOA, dale, creas vos la sala?

Comment: @Marcos y Noveember [Sala](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147678/ochoa)

Comment: Invalid utf8 character string: 'n\xBF'   @Marcos

Comment: @Noveember, métase en la sala de chat.